# EmberJS {{#linkTo}} a model that isn't loaded yet

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am working on my first significant Ember.js app, and have been running into some roadblocks. After hitting one-too-many show-stopping bugs with ember-data, I have decided to roll my own models using Ember.Object (for now at least - ember-data looks like it will be real awesome, real soon).

My basic model structure is:

- Album (has photo album-specific attrs, and references a collection of images)
- Images (an ArrayProxy collection of Image models, which tracks collection-level attrs like 'currentImage', and 'nextImage')
- Image

I have a `{{#linkTo}`} helper in my template that is supposed to allow the user to click to the next image in the set, like so:

```
<button>
    {{#linkTo image controllers.images.nextImage}}
        Next Image
    {{/linkTo}}
</button>
```

This template has the context of the `AlbumController`, which `needs: ["images"]`. `controllers.images.nextImage` is a computed property, that figures out ID of the currently-displayed image, then uses it to find the `Image` model for the next model in the `Images` ArrayProxy collection.

**My problem is this:**

Upon page load, I receive an error message `Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.`

I'm assuming this is because the `{{#linkTo}}` helper is trying to get the `id` property from the return of `controllers.image.nextImage`, which is a computed property that relies on the `Images` collection being loaded from the server. This async behaviour is being handled with promises behind-the-scenes, but the `{{#linkTo}}` helper seems to required a valid context to be returned *immediately upon page load*.

**My questions are these:**

- Has anybody else had to handle this kind of situation, where they're not using ember-data and had to use `{{#linkTo}}` helpers with computed properties that weren't immediately available?
- Can anyone suggest workarounds that don't fight Ember's way of doing things?

Some of my thoughts are:

- make the computed property return a dummy context, that *somehow* gets replaced with a valid model after load
- use an `{{#action}}` helper instead of `{{#linkTo}}`

I have [written up a JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/apuvic/2/edit) which is mostly code-complete, except I couldn't manipulate the hash URL to trigger the nested routes, so I had to do everything in the application template.

Comment: I have successfully worked around the issue by using an `{{action}}` helper, and making a reasonable assumption that the action won't be triggered until the required data is loaded. It still feels like I'm missing something key about Ember and `{{#linkTo}}`, but perhaps future improvements in __ember-data__ will make this a non-issue.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Anyone have any insights here?

Comment: You could put the link in an if, like ''if id then show link'' ore something.

Comment: I think this issue is resolved since ember 1.0.0. The linkTo helper will "wait" for the model to be available